# Vb.net Get gif current frame number + stop animation + play animation

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
picturebox1.image = image.fromfile("c:/anim.gif")
```

after i import the animation, i want to **Stop the animation**

something like:

```
picturebox1.stop()
```

(I know that there's is no such thing "Stop()")

After that i stoped the animation i want to **Play the animation** by click or something

```
b_click
picturebox1.start()
```

and now i want to get the **current frame number** of the animation

```
picturebox1.frameNumber
```

if there is no such way to do it with picturebox control, so what is the control that can stop play and get frame number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link, it may help you out! i dont think there is a way in which you can put an animation in to a picture box, the msdn article shows you how to create your own control in which you can place your animation and then customise the events that you fire to get it to play/stop etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446483.aspx

Comment: from where im download the "AnimateCtl"?

Comment: Its not a control that you can download, it is a custom control that you create. If you follow the steps in that link, then you will create the custom control and have your own custom made animation control.

Answer (score -1):

1. put the gif image in a picture box
2. add a button ....

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       If PictureBox1.Enabled = False Then
           PictureBox1.Enabled = True
       ElseIf PictureBox1.Enabled = True Then
           PictureBox1.Enabled = False
       End If
   End Sub